# Libc hypot function seems to return incorrect results for double type... why?

Tags: c++, floating-point, sse, glibc, hypotenuse

```
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        #define NUM1 -0.031679909079365576
        #define NUM2 -0.11491794452567111

        std::cout << "double precision :"<< std::endl;
        typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;
        std::cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10);
        std::cout << std::hypot((double)NUM1, (double)NUM2);
        std::cout << " VS sqrt :" << sqrt((double )NUM1*(double )NUM1 
                                  + (double )NUM2*(double )NUM2) << std::endl;

        std::cout << "long double precision :"<< std::endl;
        typedef std::numeric_limits<long double > ldbl;
        std::cout.precision(ldbl::max_digits10);
        std::cout << std::hypot((long double)NUM1, (long double)NUM2);
        std::cout << " VS sqrt :" << sqrt((long double )NUM1*(long double )NUM1 + (long double )NUM2*(long double )NUM2);
}
```

Returns under Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 clang or gcc, whatever optimisation, glic 2.25):

double precision :
0.1192046585217293 VS sqrt :0.1192046585217293**2**

long double precision :
0.119204658521729311251 VS sqrt :0.119204658521729311251

According to the cppreference :

*Implementations usually guarantee precision of **less than 1 ulp** (units in the last place): GNU, BSD, Open64
std::hypot(x, y) is equivalent to std::abs(std::complex(x,y))
POSIX specifies that underflow may only occur when both arguments are subnormal and the correct result is also subnormal (this forbids naive implementations)*

So, hypot((double)NUM1, (double)NUM2) should return 0.11920465852172932, i suppose (as naive sqrt implementation).
On windows, using MSVC 64 bit, this is the case.

Why do we see this difference using glibc ? How is it possible to solve this inconsistency ?

Comment: `std::abs(std::complex(x,y))` is not required to be computed as `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`, and neither is `std::hypot(x,y)`.    You're assuming, implicitly, that it is.    Typically the calculation will be done in a way that doesn't overflow, even if calculation of `x*x` or of `y*y` would overflow.    Such differences in the calculation method can explain the practically insignificant difference you are seeing.   Bear in mind that (except for values with very specific properties) floating point values are an *approximation*, and errors tend to propagate through operations.

Comment: The values are adjacent in IEEE754 double representation. In hex-float: `0x1.e84324de1b575p-4` vs `0x1.e84324de1b576p-4`. Both answers are < 1 ULP from the 'exact' answer (the `long double` result is between `double` values).

Comment: Incidentally, you should probably include `<cmath>` in C++, not `<tgmath.h>`. I am not as familiar with the C++ specification as with C’s, but I would not expect the macros defined by `<tgmath.h>` to be accessed by C++’s `std::sqrt` template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 0.1192046585217293**2** is represented by `0x1.e84324de1b576p-4` (as a double)
- 0.1192046585217293**0** is represented by `0x1.e84324de1b575p-4` (as a double)
- 0.1192046585217293**1**1251 is the long-double result, which we can assume is correct to a couple more decimal places.  i.e. the exact result is closer to rounded up result.

Those FP bit-patterns differ only in the low bit of the mantissa (aka significand), and **the exact result is between them**.  **So they each have less than 1 ulp of rounding error,** achieving what typical implementations (including glibc) aim for.

Unlike IEEE-754 "basic" operations (add/sub/mul/div/sqrt), `hypot` is not required to be "correctly rounded".  That means <= 0.5 ulp of error.  Achieving that would be much slower for operations the HW doesn't provide directly.  (e.g. do extended-precision calculation with at least a couple extra definitely-correct bits, so you can round to the nearest double, like the hardware does for basic operations)

It happens that in this case, the naive calculation method produced the correctly-rounded result while glibc's "safe" implementation of `std::hypot` (that has to avoid underflow when squaring small numbers before adding) produced a result with >0.5 but <1 ulp of error.

---

You didn't specify whether you were using MSVC in 32-bit mode.

Presumably 32-bit mode would be using x87 for FP math, giving extra temporary precision.  Although some MSVC versions' CRT code sets the x87 FPU's internal precision to round to 53-bit mantissa after every operation, so it behaves like SSE2 using actual `double`, except with a wider exponent range.  See  [Bruce Dawson's blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/).

So I don't know if there's any reason beyond luck that MSVC's `std::hypot` got the correctly-rounded result for this.

Note that `long double` in MSVC is the same type as 64-bit `double`; that C++ implementation doesn't expose x86 / x86-64's 80-bit hardware extended-precision type.  (64-bit mantissa).

Comment: BTW, I used https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ to get the FP bit-patterns.  For single-precision, https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html is a lot nicer, but I don't know of one as nice for double-precision.